# How to disable individual options in a Zend_Form_Element_Radio

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

Is it possible to disable individual options in a `Zend_Form_Element_Radio`? That is, I'd like to add `disabled="disabled"` to certain input tags.

Does the Zend Framework include this functionality? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
$element->setMultiOptions(array (
 'songs' => 'songs',
 'lyrics' => 'lyrics',
 'artists' => 'artists'
));
$element->setAttrib('disable', array('lyrics', 'songs'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've not tried it out yet, but as soon as I have I'll let you know.

Comment: Confirmed in ZF 1.11.11. This answer should be accepted instead.

Comment: This answer should be accepted because it is the right one. I have tried, it works.

Comment: My apologies for not accepting this answer earlier! Better late than never, right?

Answer (score 0):

It works best on the option-key. Here is a function for disabling every option except the currently active one:

```
/**
 * This function disables all options of the given selectElement, except for the active one
 * @param \Zend_Form_Element_Select $selectElement
 * @throws \Zend_Form_Exception
 */
private function disableAllOtherOptions(\Zend_Form_Element_Select $selectElement)
{
    $theOneAndOnlyActiveValue = $selectElement->getValue();
    $optionsToDisable = [];
    foreach ($selectElement->options as $key => $option) {
        if ($key <> $theOneAndOnlyActiveValue) {
            $optionsToDisable[] = $key;
        }
    }
    $selectElement->setAttrib('disable', $optionsToDisable);
}
```